# How to automate the Updating/Editing of Amazon Data Pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-data-pipeline

I want to use AWS Data Pipeline service and have created some using the manual JSON based mechanism which uses the AWS CLI to create, put and activate the pipeline.

My question is that how can I automate the editing or updating of the pipeline if something changes in the pipeline definition? Things that I can imagine changing could be schedule time, addition or removal of Activities or Preconditions, references to DataNodes, resources definition etc.

Once the pipeline is created, we cannot edit quite a few things as mentioned here in the official doc: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-manage-pipeline-modify-console.html#dp-edit-pipeline-limits

This makes me believe that if I want to automate the updating of pipeline then I would have to delete and re-create/activate a new pipeline? If yes, then the next question is that how can I create a automated process which identifies the previous version's ID, deletes it and creates a new one? Essentially trying to build a release management flow for this where the configuration JSON file is released and deployed automatically.

Most commands like activate, delete, list-runs, put-pipeline-definition etc. take the pipeline-id which is not known until a new pipeline created. I am unable to find anything which remains constant across updates or recreation (the unique-id and name parameters of the createpipeline command are consistent but then I can't use them for the above mentioned tasks (I need pipeline-id for that.

Of course I can try writing shell scripts which grep and search the output and try to create a script but is there any other better way? Some other info that I am missing?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot edit schedules completely or change references so creating/deleting pipelines seems to be the best way for your scenario.

You'll need the pipeline-id to delete a pipeline. Is it not possible to keep a record of that somewhere? You can have a file with the last used id stored locally or in S3 for instance.

Some other ways I can think of are:

- If you have only 1 pipeline in the account you can list-pipelines and
  use the only result
- If you have the pipeline name you can list-pipelines and find the id

Comment: Thanks. In face of no other way to this, option# 2 is what I am gearing towards as well. Though it does involved parsing output of a shell command which I was trying to avoid.

Comment: FWIW,  I also found this Pipewelder [link](http://pipewelder.readthedocs.org/en/latest/README.html#overview) which helps in at least automating the process.